# Using callback function to prevent an action

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm using a [drag and drop script](https://github.com/jaysalvat/ezdz) which converts the file input field into a drag and drop area. As soon you drag an image, it inserts in the input field.

I do not want it to add automatically. I want to add it in the input field only after a button `.add` is clicked. I cannot figure out if that can be done, is it possible to somehow use the **accept** call back function and tell it to only add if the button is clicked, otherwise remove the dragged file from the input field?

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />

$('#photo').ezdz({  
    accept: function() {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the input by regular html:

```
<input type="file" disabled />
```

and then connect the 'add' btn with an event to enable or disable the file input, if you use jquery:

```
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using js to set a variable to true when add is clicked. Then in your callback check if that variable is true. If not, remove the file from the input.

```
var add = false;

$('button#add').on('click', function(){
    add = true;
 }

$('#photo').ezdz({  
    accept: function() {
       if( add != true ) {
           // code to remove image from input 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect but it would be possible to display a confirmation after a file had been dropped and then remove it if they choose like this

https://jsfiddle.net/2t8yq0ac/1/

```
var $photo = $('#photo');

function photoChange(e) {
    var ok = confirm("Are you sure you want to add this file?");

    if(!ok) {
        $photo.replaceWith($photo = $photo.clone());

        $photo.on("change", photoChange);
    }
}

$photo.on("change", photoChange);
```